# 3D Hexagonal Grid CSS based not displaying as wanted

Tags: html, css, angularjs

The goal of this is to make a dynamic Hexagonal Grid using CSS, so that when a new div with certain class (eg. 'hexes') is added to the view the grid would automatically reorganize the hexes in a circular or rectangular way.

So far nothing of this has been done, what i have is a grid with lots of hexes, with some animations, they're ordered by columns of 4 hex-boxes, we can add rows to the columns, or we can add columns with rows, but they aren't responsive either self-ordered.

Here's a snippet of the mentioned above

```css
body { background-color: #171d25; }

.container {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  height: 500px;
  -webkit-perspective: 700px;
  perspective: 700px;
  z-index: 10;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container .honeycomb {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -465px;
  padding-left: 18px;
  left: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  height: 450px;
  width: 930px;
  -ms-transform: rotateX(45deg) rotateY(0deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(45deg) rotateY(0deg);
  transform: rotateX(45deg) rotateY(0deg);
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -ms-transform-origin: center 65%;
  -webkit-transform-origin: center 65%;
  transform-origin: center 65%;
  z-index: 5;
}

.container .honeycomb .column {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 62px;
}

.container .honeycomb .column:nth-child(odd) { margin-top: 36px; }

.container .honeycomb .hex {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  height: 72px;
  width: 62px;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50);
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.container .honeycomb .hex:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  -ms-transform: translateZ(20px);
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(20px);
  transform: translateZ(20px);
  -webkit-transition-duration: 200ms;
  transition-duration: 200ms;
}

.container .honeycomb .hex:hover .content {
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(enabled=false);
  opacity: 1;
  -ms-transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(-40px) translateY(-50px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(-40px) translateY(-50px);
  transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(-40px) translateY(-50px);
}

.container .honeycomb .hex .wrapper {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.container .honeycomb .hex .wrapper .color-1 { background: #ffbc06; }

.container .honeycomb .hex .wrapper .color-1:before { border-right-color: #ffbc06; }

.container .honeycomb .hex .wrapper .color-1:after { border-left-color: #ffbc06; }

.container .honeycomb .hex .content {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -80px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0);
  opacity: 0;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out 0.1s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out 0.1s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.1s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out 0.1s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out 0.1s;
  -ms-transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(-40px) translateY(-40px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(-40px) translateY(-40px);
  transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(-40px) translateY(-40px);
  pointer-events: none;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

.container .honeycomb .hex .content strong {
  display: block;
  font: 600 26px/1.1 verdana, sans-serif;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-shadow: -1px -1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

.container .honeycomb .hex .content small {
  display: block;
  font: 15px/1.1 verdana, sans-serif;
}

.container .honeycomb .shadows {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -15%;
  left: -15%;
  height: 130%;
  width: 130%;
  background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(closest-side, rgba(23, 29, 37, 0), #171d25);
  background-image: radial-gradient(closest-side, rgba(23, 29, 37, 0), #171d25);
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=90);
  opacity: 0.9;
  -ms-transform: translateZ(10px);
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(10px);
  transform: translateZ(10px);
  pointer-events: none;
}

.hexagon {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 36px;
  height: 62px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.hexagon:before,
.hexagon:after {
  content: "";
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  border-top: 31px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 31px solid transparent;
}

.hexagon:before {
  border-right: 18px solid #ffffff;
  left: -18px;
}

.hexagon:after {
  border-left: 18px solid #ffffff;
  right: -18px;
}

.hidden { display: none; }
```

```html
<body>  
<h1 style="margin:150px auto 30px auto; color:#fff" align="center">3D Hexagon Grid Layout Demo</h1>
<div class="container">
  <div class="honeycomb">
    <div class="hexes-1 column"> <a class="hex">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="hexagon color-1"></div>
      </div>
      <span class="content"> <strong>CSSScript</strong> <small>i'm a hexagon</small> </span> </a> <a class="hex">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="hexagon color-1"></div>
      </div>
      <span class="content"> <strong>CSSScript</strong> <small>i'm a hexagon</small> </span> </a> <a class="hex">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="hexagon color-1"></div>
      </div>
      <span class="content"> <strong>CSSScript</strong> <small>i'm a hexagon</small> </span> </a> <a class="hex">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="hexagon color-1"></div>
      </div>
      <span class="content"> <strong>CSSScript</strong> <small>i'm a hexagon</small> </span> </a> </div>
    <div class="hexes-2 column"> <a class="hex">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="hexagon color-1"></div>
      </div>
      <span class="content"> <strong>CSSScript</strong> <small>i'm a hexagon</small> </span> </a> <a class="hex">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="hexagon color-1"></div>
      </div>
      <span class="content"> <strong>CSSScript</strong> <small>i'm a hexagon</small> </span> </a> <a class="hex">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="hexagon color-1"></div>
      </div>
      <span class="content"> <strong>CSSScript</strong> <small>i'm a hexagon</small> </span> </a> <a class="hex">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="hexagon color-1"></div>
      </div>
      <span class="content"> <strong>CSSScript</strong> <small>i'm a hexagon</small> </span> </a> <a class="hex">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="hexagon color-1"></div>
      </div>
      <span class="content"> <strong>CSSScript</strong> <small>i'm a hexagon</small> </span> </a> </div>
    <div class="hexes-3 column"> <a class="hex">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="hexagon color-1"></div>
      </div>
      <span class="content"> <strong>CSSScript</strong> <small>i'm a hexagon</small> </span> </a> <a class="hex">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="hexagon color-1"></div>
      </div>
      <span class="content"> <strong>CSSScript</strong> <small>i'm a hexagon</small> </span> </a> <a class="hex">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="hexagon color-1"></div>
      </div>
      <span class="content"> <strong>CSSScript</strong> <small>i'm a hexagon</small> </span> </a> <a class="hex">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="hexagon color-1"></div>
      </div>
      <span class="content"> <strong>CSSScript</strong> <small>i'm a hexagon</small> </span> </a> </div>
    <div class="hexes-4 column"> <a class="hex">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="hexagon color-1"></div>
      </div>
      <span class="content"> <strong>CSSScript</strong> <small>i'm a hexagon</small> </span> </a> <a class="hex">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="hexagon color-1"></div>
      </div>
      <span class="content"> <strong>CSSScript</strong> <small>i'm a hexagon</small> </span> </a> <a class="hex">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="hexagon color-1"></div>
      </div>
      <span class="content"> <strong>CSSScript</strong> <small>i'm a hexagon</small> </span> </a> <a class="hex">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="hexagon color-1"></div>
      </div>
      <span class="content"> <strong>CSSScript</strong> <small>i'm a hexagon</small> </span> </a> <a class="hex">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="hexagon color-1"></div>
      </div>
      <span class="content"> <strong>CSSScript</strong> <small>i'm a hexagon</small> </span> </a> </div>
    <div class="hexes-5 column"> <a class="hex">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="hexagon color-1"></div>
      </div>
      <span class="content"> <strong>CSSScript</strong> <small>i'm a hexagon</small> </span> </a> <a class="hex">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="hexagon color-1"></div>
      </div>
      <span class="content"> <strong>CSSScript</strong> <small>i'm a hexagon</small> </span> </a> <a class="hex">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="hexagon color-1"></div>
      </div>
      <span class="content"> <strong>CSSScript</strong> <small>i'm a hexagon</small> </span> </a> <a class="hex">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="hexagon color-1"></div>
      </div>
      <span class="content"> <strong>CSSScript</strong> <small>i'm a hexagon</small> </span> </a> </div>
    <div class="hexes-6 column"> <a class="hex">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="hexagon color-1"></div>
      </div>
      <span class="content"> <strong>CSSScript</strong> <small>i'm a hexagon</small> </span> </a> <a class="hex">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="hexagon color-1"></div>
      </div>
      <span class="content"> <strong>CSSScript</strong> <small>i'm a hexagon</small> </span> </a> <a class="hex">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="hexagon color-1"></div>
      </div>
      <span class="content"> <strong>CSSScript</strong> <small>i'm a hexagon</small> </span> </a> <a class="hex">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="hexagon color-1"></div>
      </div>
      <span class="content"> <strong>CSSScript</strong> <small>i'm a hexagon</small> </span> </a> <a class="hex">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="hexagon color-1"></div>
      </div>
      <span class="content"> <strong>CSSScript</strong> <small>i'm a hexagon</small> </span> </a> </div>
    <div class="hexes-7 column"> <a class="hex">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="hexagon color-1"></div>
      </div>
      <span class="content"> <strong>CSSScript</strong> <small>i'm a hexagon</small> </span> </a> <a class="hex">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="hexagon color-1"></div>
      </div>
      <span class="content"> <strong>CSSScript</strong> <small>i'm a hexagon</small> </span> </a> <a class="hex">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="hexagon color-1"></div>
      </div>
      <span class="content"> <strong>CSSScript</strong> <small>i'm a hexagon</small> </span> </a> <a class="hex">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="hexagon color-1"></div>
      </div>
      <span class="content"> <strong>CSSScript</strong> <small>i'm a hexagon</small> </span> </a> </div>
    <div class="hexes-8 column"> <a class="hex">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="hexagon color-1"></div>
      </div>
      <span class="content"> <strong>CSSScript</strong> <small>i'm a hexagon</small> </span> </a> <a class="hex">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="hexagon color-1"></div>
      </div>
      <span class="content"> <strong>CSSScript</strong> <small>i'm a hexagon</small> </span> </a> <a class="hex">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="hexagon color-1"></div>
      </div>
      <span class="content"> <strong>CSSScript</strong> <small>i'm a hexagon</small> </span> </a> <a class="hex">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="hexagon color-1"></div>
      </div>
      <span class="content"> <strong>CSSScript</strong> <small>i'm a hexagon</small> </span> </a> <a class="hex">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="hexagon color-1"></div>
      </div>
      <span class="content"> <strong>CSSScript</strong> <small>i'm a hexagon</small> </span> </a> </div>
    <div class="hexes-9 column"> <a class="hex">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="hexagon color-1"></div>
      </div>
      <span class="content"> <strong>CSSScript</strong> <small>i'm a hexagon</small> </span> </a> <a class="hex">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="hexagon color-1"></div>
      </div>
      <span class="content"> <strong>CSSScript</strong> <small>i'm a hexagon</small> </span> </a> <a class="hex">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="hexagon color-1"></div>
      </div>
      <span class="content"> <strong>CSSScript</strong> <small>i'm a hexagon</small> </span> </a> <a class="hex">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="hexagon color-1"></div>
      </div>
      <span class="content"> <strong>CSSScript</strong> <small>i'm a hexagon</small> </span> </a> </div>
    <div class="hexes-10 column"> <a class="hex">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="hexagon color-1"></div>
      </div>
      <span class="content"> <strong>CSSScript</strong> <small>i'm a hexagon</small> </span> </a> <a class="hex">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="hexagon color-1"></div>
      </div>
      <span class="content"> <strong>CSSScript</strong> <small>i'm a hexagon</small> </span> </a> <a class="hex">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="hexagon color-1"></div>
      </div>
      <span class="content"> <strong>CSSScript</strong> <small>i'm a hexagon</small> </span> </a> <a class="hex">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="hexagon color-1"></div>
      </div>
      <span class="content"> <strong>CSSScript</strong> <small>i'm a hexagon</small> </span> </a> <a class="hex">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="hexagon color-1"></div>
      </div>
      <span class="content"> <strong>CSSScript</strong> <small>i'm a hexagon</small> </span> </a> </div>
    <div class="hexes-11 column"> <a class="hex">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="hexagon color-1"></div>
      </div>
      <span class="content"> <strong>CSSScript</strong> <small>i'm a hexagon</small> </span> </a> <a class="hex">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="hexagon color-1"></div>
      </div>
      <span class="content"> <strong>CSSScript</strong> <small>i'm a hexagon</small> </span> </a> <a class="hex">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="hexagon color-1"></div>
      </div>
      <span class="content"> <strong>CSSScript</strong> <small>i'm a hexagon</small> </span> </a> <a class="hex">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="hexagon color-1"></div>
      </div>
      <span class="content"> <strong>CSSScript</strong> <small>i'm a hexagon</small> </span> </a> </div>
    <div class="hexes-12 column"> <a class="hex">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="hexagon color-1"></div>
      </div>
      <span class="content"> <strong>CSSScript</strong> <small>i'm a hexagon</small> </span> </a> <a class="hex">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="hexagon color-1"></div>
      </div>
      <span class="content"> <strong>CSSScript</strong> <small>i'm a hexagon</small> </span> </a> <a class="hex">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="hexagon color-1"></div>
      </div>
      <span class="content"> <strong>CSSScript</strong> <small>i'm a hexagon</small> </span> </a> <a class="hex">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="hexagon color-1"></div>
      </div>
      <span class="content"> <strong>CSSScript</strong> <small>i'm a hexagon</small> </span> </a> <a class="hex">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="hexagon color-1"></div>
      </div>
      <span class="content"> <strong>CSSScript</strong> <small>i'm a hexagon</small> </span> </a> </div>
    <div class="hexes-13 column"> <a class="hex">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="hexagon color-1"></div>
      </div>
      <span class="content"> <strong>CSSScript</strong> <small>i'm a hexagon</small> </span> </a> <a class="hex">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="hexagon color-1"></div>
      </div>
      <span class="content"> <strong>CSSScript</strong> <small>i'm a hexagon</small> </span> </a> <a class="hex">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="hexagon color-1"></div>
      </div>
      <span class="content"> <strong>CSSScript</strong> <small>i'm a hexagon</small> </span> </a> <a class="hex">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="hexagon color-1"></div>
      </div>
      <span class="content"> <strong>CSSScript</strong> <small>i'm a hexagon</small> </span> </a> </div>
    <div class="hexes-14 column"> <a class="hex">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="hexagon color-1"></div>
      </div>
      <span class="content"> <strong>CSSScript</strong> <small>i'm a hexagon</small> </span> </a> <a class="hex">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="hexagon color-1"></div>
      </div>
      <span class="content"> <strong>CSSScript</strong> <small>i'm a hexagon</small> </span> </a> <a class="hex">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="hexagon color-1"></div>
      </div>
      <span class="content"> <strong>CSSScript</strong> <small>i'm a hexagon</small> </span> </a> <a class="hex">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="hexagon color-1"></div>
      </div>
      <span class="content"> <strong>CSSScript</strong> <small>i'm a hexagon</small> </span> </a> <a class="hex">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="hexagon color-1"></div>
      </div>
      <span class="content"> <strong>CSSScript</strong> <small>i'm a hexagon</small> </span> </a> </div>
    <div class="hexes-13 column"> <a class="hex">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="hexagon color-1"></div>
      </div>
      <span class="content"> <strong>CSSScript</strong> <small>i'm a hexagon</small> </span> </a> <a class="hex">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="hexagon color-1"></div>
      </div>
      <span class="content"> <strong>CSSScript</strong> <small>i'm a hexagon</small> </span> </a> <a class="hex">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="hexagon color-1"></div>
      </div>
      <span class="content"> <strong>CSSScript</strong> <small>i'm a hexagon</small> </span> </a> <a class="hex">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="hexagon color-1"></div>
      </div>
      <span class="content"> <strong>CSSScript</strong> <small>i'm a hexagon</small> </span> </a> </div>
    <div class="shadows"></div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Now if i would like half of the hexes i would get rid off of seven div with class 'column'... but the hexes won't expand neither get centered.

[Here's an attempt](https://jsfiddle.net/JSolorzano/91x6avzh/embedded/result/) to make them bigger and display them centered, basically what was done here is make bigger the square, adjust some left and right values, nothing solid...

Someone told me to use @media queries, but i haven't worked with them so much... What's needed is to make the grid resposive, and also dynamic, the purpose is to make it work with AngularJS using an ng-repeat, so that we won't know the number of options, and it will order them to make them view nice. Also would like to know how to do some other stuff like insert an image in the middle of the hex, display an image on top of the name of the hex, and maybe display some info with an animation...

Answer (score 0):

The only solution available yet is indeed using media queries. The concept is that you know the width of the hexagons, you use `:nth-child()` selector to push every second row instead of wrapping the hexagons in rows, and just make them `inline-block`, and then setup all the breakpoints with media query based on your hexagons width and only change the value inside `:nth-child()` when the viewport width changes.

Example:

```
<span class="hex"></span>
<span class="hex"></span>
<span class="hex"></span>
<span class="hex"></span>
<span class="hex"></span>
<span class="hex"></span>
<style>
  .hex{
    width:100px;
  }
  @media(min-width: 200px) and (max-width: 299px){
    .hex:nth-child(3n){
      margin-left:50px;
    }
  }
  @media(min-width: 300px) and (max-width: 399px){
    .hex:nth-child(5n+4){
      margin-left:50px;
    }
  }
  @media(min-width: 400px) and (max-width: 499px){
    .hex:nth-child(7n+5){
      margin-left:50px;
    }
  }
  @media(min-width: 500px) and (max-width: 599px){
    .hex:nth-child(9n+6){
      margin-left:50px;
    }
  }
</style>
```

The formaula is:

```
for(i = 2; i < .hex(length); i++){
  @media(min-width: i * .hex(width) ) and (max-width: (i * 2 * .hex(width)) - 1){
    .hex:nth-child(((2*i)-1)n+(i+1)){
      margin-left:.hex(width)/2;
    }
  }
}
```

This works well for horizontal (pointy) hex grids, but the idea can be easily adapted for vertical (flat) hex grids changing a bit the formula above.

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/q2my8vcn/
(Already tweaked some, still not perfect but you can see the basic idea quite well in action.)

Comment: Would you like to make an example of your solution?

Comment: I like the way your idea seems, could you make a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/) or [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) example? something like what i posted?, i don't get how to see the result?

Comment: Added the fiddle, didn't think about it, but you actually need to handle every half hexagon line-breaks, and set  the max-width on the media queries as well.

Comment: Seems decent, but i can't set this as a right answer, it doesn't cover all the requirements: image on the hex, animation, reorganize the hexes responsively by equally amounts, what it does so far is insert the hex in a new line when the display has changed.

Comment: I don't agree. It does reorganize the hexes, all you have to do is wrap them in a dynamically sized container of your choice. The animations can be easily done using some 3D CSS, as well as the image above them. It seemed to me you already resolved that part of it. What my code does is to handle the hexagons like inline-blocks while maintaining the hexa-grid of the rows. So I guess my answer is sufficient, but maybe someone will come and do it for you.